# SQL Query to locate redundant data rows

Tags: sql-server

I have two SQL tables on SQL Server 2008 :

```
GameData 

GameID PK 
GameReleaseDate
GameTitle 
GameCoverClobID FK


GameClob

GameCoverClobID PK
Filename
```

So over time the covers are updated and whatnot, and as a result, I have several items in GameClob that have no matching ID in GameData are now effectively redundant data. I'd like to be able to delete these items, however I was wondering is there a SQL query that I can run, that will just show me the rows in GameClob that have no GameCoverClobID in the GameData table.

I hope I have explained this correctly, any questions, please ask.

Appreciate it!

Comment: You should take a look at this article by @Quassnoi: http://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `WHERE NOT EXISTS` clause should be faster than `LEFT JOIN` and `NOT IN` because it shortcuts when the first record is found.

```
SELECT * 
FROM GameClob gc
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                    FROM GameData gd 
                   WHERE gc.GameCoverClobID = gd.GameCoverClobID )
```

To prevent this problem in the future it is best to create a foreign key between the 2 tables

```
ALTER TABLE GameClob 
ADD CONSTRAINT fkGameClobGameData 
FOREIGN KEY (GameCoverClobID) 
REFERENCES GameData(GameCoverClobID)
```

Comment: `NOT IN` Should have exactly the same plan as `NOT EXISTS` assuming `gamedata.GameCoverClobID` is not `NULL`-able.

Comment: @Martin Agree, although I prefer the use of EXISTS() as it "always" works. The `LEFT JOIN` solution will need an additional `Filter` pass to get the result.

Answer (score 2):

```
select * 
from gameclob 
where GameCoverClobID not in (select GameCoverClobID from gamedata)
```

Comment: I believe you want to change the WHERE clause to use GameCoverClobID.

Answer (score 0):

`LEFT JOIN` should be faster than `NOT IN`...

```
SELECT *
FROM gameclob gc
LEFT JOIN gamedata gd
    ON gs.GameCoverClobI = gc.GameCoverClobID
WHERE gd.gameclobid IS NULL
```

Comment: Probably because your assertion about speed is flatly contradicted by the link in the comments!

Comment: @Martin - just read that actually :)  My assertion is based on experience, but I think in the case the OP posted I would be wrong.